# What is the right way to implement an inverted pendulum controller for real HW and simulation in ROS2 and Gazebo Sim

Tags: ros2-control, gz-sim

**Context :**
I have been using ROS in hobby projects for the last 10 years but keep in mind I'm not a professionnal software developper.
I would like to step-up my game by implementing a "teen size" inverted pendulum balancing robot. Actually, it would eventually be more of a wheeled biped, but let's simplify the problem by locking the knees and hips so that it behaves like a "segway" for the time beeing.

[image: Movee Simu]
[image: Movee Real]

The robot has an embedded computer , a Jetson, as well as a "embedded gateway" with a USB<=>CAN electronics, a 200Hz AHRS module and H7 STM32 (and plenty other sensors and hardware not relevant to the question) .
So I have plenty of processing power available on the high level as well as low level side, but I'm still hesitating on how to dispatch the algorithms.

I would like to have a simulation as realistic as possible to be able to try several control laws without constantly breaking my house and my robot and maybe also try some RL. But the algorithms developped in the simulation must be easily transferable to the physical robot eventually. I've done most of the work on Gazebo Sim so far, but I'm open to argumented alternatives :)

**HW Architecture**
[image: HW Robot Architecture]

**Hypothesis**
Here is the order of magnitude I have in mind when designing the architecture, please correct me if mistaken :

- 1 : The "low level control loop" between the IMU and the 2 driving wheels should run at least at **200 Hz**, maybe 500Hz to have a very stable balancing of the robot especially when idle. (let's say something [as smooth as Handle from BostonDyn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3L2e_n4tDc&t=22s))
- 2 : Latency of communication between MCU and CPU over USB 2.0 would be around 20ms, thus not adapted to the high frequency/low latency control loop required by a balancing robot

**Question**
How to dispatch the algorithm between **A** and **B** to be efficient in the real robot and realistic/representative of the reality in the simulation ?

Here are my suggestions:

***Option Architecture 1 :*** The easy way for the development, also very good simu / real representativity and portability but probably bad performance on the actual robot.
[image: Architecture 1]

The bright side is I can use standard topics, ros2_controllers and gazebo plugin everywhere ! Also I can easily try various ROS control nodes (fuzy logic, LQR, ...) and compare performances with ROS plots tools. But the latency in the control loop from the USB communication might ruin all performance, also I would have to spend time to make the high_level codes running on a RT kernel ubuntu.

***Option Architecture 2 :***

[image: Architecture 2]

The critical control loop remains on the MCU for low latency and high frequency, but then how to implement a 200-500Hz running loop in Gazebo in a representative way ? Are there examples of gz_sim plugins with internal use of the IMU signal for high frequency control that will not go trough ROS ? If that were the right way to go, and since balancing robots are common, there should already be a "standard" balancing_robot_plugin like the diff_drive or the ackermann, right ?

**Questions :**

- I guess I'm mostly looking for advices and returns of experience. When trying to play with high frequency/low latency control control loops above 100Hz, we reach ROS limitation and there is obviously dedicated developement to do, but which way to go ?

Option 1 with a lot of headache on making high level ros nodes execute on a RT kernel (my understanding is that ROS2 was trying to enable better real-time applications, but I haven't found much ressources dealing with how nodes at 100Hz+ behave especially with USB in the loop.

Option 2 with a lot of headache on implementing a Gazebo plugin that behaves closely like the embedded code on the MCU and internal IMU will. Also why isn't there examples of such implementations of high frequency control loop plugins in Gazebo ? I feel like ros_control is trying to solve such issue on ROS side, but also no example of control nodes with an IMU in the loop.

- Also, any feedback or actual figures from existing robots for the hypothesis would be welcome :)

Sorry for the long post, but I guess that is a fairly common reflection for advanced robotics that needs to be documented.

I [left the drawings on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/kytheralab/applications/manitoba/balancee_stack/-/blob/main/ROS_architecture.drawio?ref_type=heads) if anyone wants to reply with visuals.